# Change background color of TD

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to change my background color for one of the rows if one value is bigger than the other.

I tried using jQuery to change the color but it  changes the color for every row.

Here is my code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td style="width:25%"><a href="calendarevent.php?   EventId='.urlencode($row['id']).'">'.$row['date'].'</a></td>';
    echo'<td class="starttime">'.$row['start'].'</td>';
    echo'<td class="finishtime">'.$row['finish'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['total'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['cash'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';

    $start =$row['start'];
    $finish = $row['finish'];
    if ( $start<$finish ) {
       //CHANGE BACK GROUND COLOR FOR finish time to red 
    }else{
      //Keep the color as it was
    }

}
```

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: Since you are using PHP to output the values into the table cells, you can also calculate the larger of the two values and add a class to the `<tr>` tag as you output it so that it is flagged to format with a color.  Use CSS to set the background color of this class.  JavaScript, in this case, can only add a point of failure.  It's better to output the page already marked up they way you want it instead of going back with JavaScript and fixing it later.  If somebody has disable JavaScript, you'd background color script would never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is yet another way with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/7jm3R/

I created a class for the red background called redback;

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var start = parseInt($(this).find('.start').html());
    var finish = parseInt($(this).find('.finish').html());
    if(start < finish) {
        $(this).addClass('redback');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Test the value before rendering the TD, then add a specific class to the TD, then style the TD with the class

```
<style type="text/css">
    .redCell {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<?php

    // Loop Through DB Rows
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
        echo'<td style="width:25%"><a href="calendarevent.php?  EventId='.urlencode($row['id']).'">'.$row['date'].'</a></td>';
        $start =$row['start'];
        $finish = $row['finish'];

        // Test the value
        if ( $start<$finish ) {
           $class = "redCell"; // Add a new class to make it red
        }else{
          $class = ""; // Keep the color as it was
        }

        echo'<td class="starttime">'.$row['start'].'</td>';

        // Add the style to the TD
        echo'<td class="finishtime '.$class.'">'.$row['finish'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['total'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['cash'].'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $style = ''
    $start =$row['start'];
    $finish = $row['finish'];
    if ( $start<$finish ) {
       $style = 'style="background-color: red"';
    }
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td style="width:25%"><a href="calendarevent.php?   EventId='.urlencode($row['id']).'">'.$row['date'].'</a></td>';
    echo'<td class="starttime">'.$row['start'].'</td>';
    echo'<td ' . $style . ' class="finishtime">'.$row['finish'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['total'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['cash'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

you do not need to do anything with jQuery, especially NOT within the table

Comment: A CSS class would be even better - it keeps the styles in your stylesheet and out of the server-side code.

Comment: Yeah for sure, I know that, that's just a small snippet/hint... the poster should be doing something himself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Place your `if` statement above your `echo`s then use it to create a class in the `tr` I couldn't tell if you wanted the whole row (`tr`) red or the specific cell (`td`) since you mentioned both, but this will style the entire row.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $start =$row['start'];
    $finish = $row['finish'];
    if ( $start<$finish ) {
      $bgRed = 'class="bgRed"';
    }else{
      $bgRed = '';
    }

    echo'<tr'.$bgRed.'>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td style="width:25%"><a href="calendarevent.php?   EventId='.urlencode($row['id']).'">'.$row['date'].'</a></td>';
    echo'<td class="starttime">'.$row['start'].'</td>';
    echo'<td class="finishtime">'.$row['finish'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['total'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['cash'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';

}
```

Then style that class appropriately:

```
.bgRed td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can't style the bg color of a row...the css selector would have to be "tr.bgRed td {background-color: red;}"

Comment: @circusdei Thanks, I forgot about that! It's been a while since I've worked with tables... I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but this should work:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var start = $(this).find('.starttime').html(); //assuming this td contains number
    var finish = $(this).find('.finishtime').html(); //assuming this td contains number
    if(start < finish) $(this).css('background', '#F00');
});
```